# Kotlin println("texte") not functionning

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I'm really new to development project and Kotlin. I did an easy code to click a button and print a message on click however it seems that even if the code is built with no error and the logcat print the message, it's a different matter on the screen since the message is not printed. I really have no clue about where the probleme come from since I've got no error message.

Here is the code (using Kotlin and Android Studio)

```
package com.example.myapplicationtest2

import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ColumnScope
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import android.util.Log
import com.example.myapplicationtest2.ui.theme.MyApplicationTEST2Theme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTEST2Theme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {
                        ClickableButton()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}


@Composable
fun ClickableButton() {
    var showHello: Boolean by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}

    Button(
        onClick = { showHello = true/* action to perform on button click */ },
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = "Who is it?")
    }
    if (showHello == true) {
        println("Hi !")
        showHello = false
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help guys

I also tried to define a boolean fonction set to true on clicking and if true prints the message but same results.

Comment: Your code does not show `println("texte")`.

Comment: Sorry I did show you the wrong code. I edited my post with the right code, it not functionning either. I also tried to do the println directly in the "Onclick" line" but same result : no result...

Comment: So are you trying to make the text visible to the user? like a pop-up of some sort?

Comment: Yes, juste make text visible to the user when clicking a button.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Composable
fun SayHello() {
    var showHello: Boolean by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
    var showHelloDialog: Boolean by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}

    when {
        showHelloDialog -> {
            AlertDialog(
                icon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Default.Warning, contentDescription = "Alert Dialog Icon")
                },
                title = {
                    Text(text = "Hi !")
                },
                text = {
                    Text(text = "I'm")
                },
                onDismissRequest = {
                    showHelloDialog = false
                },
                confirmButton = {
                    TextButton(
                        onClick = {
                            //
                        }
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Ok")
                    }
                },
                dismissButton = {
                    TextButton(
                        onClick = {
                            showHelloDialog = false
                        }
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Close")
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = { showHello = !showHello },
        ) {
            Text(text = "Show Text")
        }

        Button(
            onClick = { showHelloDialog = true },
        ) {
            Text(text = "Show Alert Dialog")
        }

        AnimatedVisibility(visible = showHello) {
            Text(text = "Hi !")

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately, I have the same result than before : nothing pops up when I click the button... Is it possible that the texte is printed outside the screen or under the button or in the same color as the backgroung?

Comment: Oh dear, thanks a lot, I'll try to understand what was wrong with the other code. However I have a lot of trouble understanding how it didn't work and show no errors... A long way left for me to learn !